# Regain access to windows after clumsily deleting Ubuntu partition (from inside windows) when getting a grub rescue screen?

Tags: grubrescue

Basically I went into disk management in windows, right clicked on the Ubuntu partition and clicked delete. It was lazy and stupid and now I've lost access to my windows and all I get is

```
error: no such device: 9a952691.....
entering rescue mode...
Grub rescue>
```

I've tried various fixes and I can't get them to work.. Help please? Preferably without need for a USB stick or windows disk or anything, can I do it from this screen?

Answer (score 0):

How about a Ubuntu live dvd?Or
Maybe this can help,basically you should use EasyBCD:
https://superuser.com/questions/381285/how-to-install-grub-from-inside-windows-7

The once you are back in Ubuntu you use grub-repair.